# Query all lists in a web on which a user has read access (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, caml

I have a SP site on which there are many lists. Some users have read access on a couple of lists and so on.

I have created a custom page that lists the name of all the lists on which the user has read access. For this requirement I loop through all the lists on the site and check through the permissions and then generate a report. I definitely feel that looping like this is not an apt solution (also a very slow one).

Can someone let me know if I can CAML query the site to query all the SP lists on the site on which I or any other user has read access? 
Hope the question is clear. Let me know if you need any other inputs.

Thanks

Amar

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Comment: So looping is the only option for my requirement in SP 2013?

Comment: Someone please help!!